# this pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, class, this

The below code is constructor of a class and this class has a member

```
int               ** busyhours      ;
```

The constructor

```
Instructor::Instructor ( int id , string name )
{
  this->id   = id   ;
  this->name = name ;

  // initialize busyhours
  this->busyhours = new int * [DAYS_WORKING] ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < DAYS_WORKING ; i++ )
  {
       busyhours[i] = new int[HOURS_PER_DAY] ;
       for ( int j = 0 ; j < HOURS_PER_DAY ; j++ )
        busyhours[i][j] = 0 ;
  }
}
```

busyhour member first used with this pointer but then it is used without this pointer. I don't understand why. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is implicit and is only needed if a parameter has the same name as the member variable

Comment: so you want to say "this" is unnecessary in this situation?

Comment: No, in *this* situation (no pun intended) it is necessary because of the names you've chosen for both your member variables and parameters (i.e. they're the same).

Comment: this is needed for name and id but not busyhours

Comment: @rabbidrabbit: This is not needed for "name" and "id" if they are properly initialized using initialization list and not assignment inside constructor's body...

Comment: If you used the initializer list it would be completely unneded:
`Instructor::Instructor(int id,string name):id(id),name(name) { ... }` and it is not needed at all for the `busyhours` member.

Answer (score 2):

Have a quick read of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it should clear a few things up.

In general I find the use of `this->` is c++ is more more a matter of personal preference, but there are situations when you could use it to to disambiguate between say a function argument and a member variable. In your example I don't see any particular reason why `this->` was used once and then not later on. It could be because `this->.` gives you the intelisense popup in visual studio which may only have been necessary the first time round to remind the author what the member variables were called.

Answer (score 1):

@WhozCraig has roughly the right idea, at least in my opinion -- but note that in this case, you do *not* need to rename the parameters. You can also use value initialization with the `new` to eliminate explicitly zeroing the data, leaving only:

```
Instructor::Instructor ( int id , string name )
   : id(id), name(name), busyhours(new int *[DAYS_WORKING])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < DAYS_WORKING; i++)
       busyhours[i] = new int[HOURS_PER_DAY]();
}
```

Of course, you should almost certainly throw all this out, and use `std::vector` instead of doing dynamic allocation yourself.

Comment: I concur on the not needing to rename params, it isn't necessary for compilation, but for someone that is not entirely sure of name-scope, it eliminates a lot of confusion (+1, btw, esp for the vector comment =P).

Comment: Throwing all out is a good advice. But std::vector is not necessary, if DAYS_WORKING is a constant. You can simply declare an array of that size. busyhours[DAYS_WORKING][HOURS_PER_DAY].

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes, you can, but unless the arrays are fairly small, you may not want to -- at least if the arrays are large at all, you may want them allocated on the free store instead of automatically (typically on the stack, with much more limited size).